# How to get session stored value in ctp(template/view file) of cake php 3.2?

Tags: php, session, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

Here i am using below code after login in php file

```html
 echo $get_user_id=$this->Auth->user('id');//getting out put 9
```

but if i am using this in ctp after login

```html
 <?= $this->Form->input('id', ['type'=>'hidden1','value'=>$get_user_id]); ?>
```

error is coming.

I have done it in another way but its still not working.
After login i have stored id in this way.

```html
                        $session = $this->request->session();
                        $session->write('User_id', $this->Auth->user('id'));
                        echo $session->read('User_id');//9
```

and try to get this value in this way in ctp file.

```html
 <?= $this->Form->input('id', ['type'=>'hidden1','value'=>$session->read('User.id')]); ?>
```

but ,its still not coming.Its only coming when i set this value to ctp

```html
$get_user_id = $this->Auth->user('id');
$this->set(compact('get_user_id'));
```

```html
 <?= $this->Form->input('id', ['type'=>'hidden1','value'=>$get_user_id); ?>//ctp file
```

Is there any way that i can get the session stored id after login in direct way(without using set.)
In cakephp 2X version it is easier to get session stored value in ctp
But not in cakephp 3X
.Sorry i am new to cakephp 3X
.Any suggestion will highly appreciate
.Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you should use Auth then User

```
$session = $this->request->session();
$session->read('Auth.User.id')
```

or

```
$this->request->session()->read('Auth.User')
```

more info- http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/sessions.html#accessing-the-session-object

Comment: but in my end its working, i am also using cakephp 3X

Comment: Ok ,it working in php file ,i mean this one $session->read('Auth.User.id')
result is coming as id,but while i am using in in ctp,error is coming.

Comment: <?= $this->Form->input('id', ['type'=>'hidden1','value'=> $session->read('Auth.User.id')]); ?>
This code i have used in ctp .

Comment: Error coming  
Error: Call to a member function read() on null
File E:\htdocs\adminCake3\adminCake3\src\Template\Users\profile.ctp
Line: 42

Comment: Yes yes the second one is coming
instead of $session->read('Auth.User.id')
If i use
   <?= $this->Form->input('id', ['type'=>'hidden1','value'=> $this->request->session()->read('Auth.User.id')]); ?>
     any way both are same only $session variable i have to define in ctp.I thought of its like cakephp 2X.

Comment: did you assign $session = $this->request->session() it, to variable?

Comment: Yes i have assigned it in controller ,but while i am doing it in this way

 
<?= $this->Form->input('id', ['type'=>'hidden1','value'=> $session->read('Auth.User.id')]); ?>
Its not working.But now its working.Now i have chnaged it to

 <?= $this->Form->input('id', ['type'=>'hidden1','value'=> $this->request->session()->read('Auth.User.id')]); ?>